# Converting SWF to HTML5 for Google Adwords

Tags: html, flash, google-ads-api, google-swiffy

i want to convert SWF files in to HTML5 for Google AdWords. After the conversion in Swiffy and uploading the file in Google AdWords the platform returns an error.

The error is "TEXT_HTML", I attached a screen shot to show the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to .zip the .html file from Swiffy and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Swiffy will not be able to convert the Flash banner correctly you need to convert the banner properly in Google Web Designer or you can get in touch with Smart Animate. They can do it for you.